# If $A$ is a contraction, then $(1-\lambda A)^{-1}=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\lambda^nA^n$ for all $|\lambda|<1$

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, hilbert-spaces, inverse, spectral-theory

Let $A$ be a self-adjoint contraction (operator norm at most $1$) on a $\mathbb R$-Hilbert space $H$. By contractivity the spectrum $\sigma(A)$ is contained in $[-1,1]$.

> Let $\lambda\in[0,1)$. How can we show that $(1-\lambda A)^{-1}=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\lambda^nA^n$?

We may note that $\lambda^{-1}$ is contained in the resolvent set $\rho(A)\supseteq\mathbb R\setminus[-1,1]$ and $1-\lambda A=\lambda(\lambda^{-1}-A)$.

Comment: This doesn't have much to do with self-adjointness. Just show that the series converges, and multiply it from the left [from.the right] with $1-\lambda A$. What do you get?

Comment: @PhoemueX I see. Since $|\lambda|<1$, $\sum_{n=0}^\infty\left\|(\lambda A)^n\right\|\le\frac1{1-|\lambda|}$. So, the series is convergent wrt the uniform operator topolgy. Now $(1-\lambda A)\sum_{n=0}^\infty(\lambda A)^n=\sum_{n=0}^\infty(1-\lambda A)(\lambda A)^n=1-\lim_{n\to\infty}(\lambda A)^n=1$, since the multiplication in $\mathfrak L(E)$ is (jointly) continuous wrt the uniform operator topology.

Comment: Exactly. This is called a Neumann series argument.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since

$\Vert A \Vert \le 1, \tag 1$

and

$\lambda \in [0, 1) \Longrightarrow 0 \le \lambda < 1, \tag 2$

the series

$S = \displaystyle \sum_0^\infty \lambda^n A^n \tag 3$

is absolutely and uniformly convergent, ***viz.***

$\left \Vert \displaystyle \sum _0^\infty \lambda^n A^n  \right \Vert \le \displaystyle  \sum _0^\infty \Vert  \lambda^n A^n \Vert$
$= \displaystyle \sum _0^\infty  \lambda^n \Vert  A^n \Vert \le  \sum _0^\infty \lambda^n \Vert  A \Vert^n \le \sum_0^\infty \lambda^n = \dfrac{1}{1 - \lambda} < \infty;  \tag 4$

we further recall the well-known algebraic identity

$(I - \lambda A) \displaystyle \sum_0^m (\lambda A)^n = I - (\lambda A)^m; \tag 5$

when we let $m \to \infty$ in this equation we obtain

$(I - \lambda A) \displaystyle \sum_0^\infty (\lambda A)^n = I; \tag 6$

(6) binds by virtue of the facts that, as has been seen in the above, the sum on the left converges to $S$ whilst $(\lambda A)^m \to 0$, since

$\Vert (\lambda A)^m \Vert = \vert \lambda \vert^m \Vert A^m \Vert \le \lambda^m \Vert A \Vert^m \le \lambda^m \to 0 \; \text{as} \; m \to \infty; \tag 7$

thus $I - \lambda A$ is invertible with

$(I - \lambda A)^{-1} = S. \tag 8$

Comment: (a) $1-\lambda A$ is even bijective, right? And it's worth mentioning that your argument is still valid when $\lambda\in(-1,1)$. (b) You've only shown that $S$ is the right-inverse (btw, there is an $a$ in $(6)$ which shouldn't be there). It's obvious that $S$ is the left-inverse as well, but is there a formal argument which ensures that we don't need to check this separately?

Comment: @0xbadf00d:  i..)  $I - \lambda A)$ is *invertible*, hence both injective and surjective, hence bijective; ii.)  $S$ is also the left inverse since the multiplicands in (5) and (6) commute.  The $a$ is a typo, will get rid of it.  Thanks for your "acceptance".  Cheers!

Comment: It's me, who needs to thank you for your answer!

Comment: @0xbadf00d:  My pleasure my friend!